# Jooq text array generated as object array

Tags: sql, types, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

given the following sql

```sql
create table something(
  id BIGSERIAL,
  something TEXT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and instructing the code generator to use DDLDatabase 
the generated item is in the form of

```java
    public final TableField<JSomethingRecord, Object[]> SOMETHING_
```

Looking around in the documentation I cannot find how can this be mapped in a `String[]`.
same applies for `varchar` and `varchar(255)`.
I shouldn't have to use an enforced type here as at least on of the three should be a valid datatype 
and not fallback to `OTHER` as it happens with the `UUID` (for which I saw there is an example for enforced types)

Am I doing / understanding something wrong or this is an expected behaviour?

The database I am using is PostGres and the generator configuration is the following

```xml
<generator>
    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase</name>
        <inputCatalog/>
        <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <key>use-attribute-converters</key>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <key>scripts</key>
                <value>src/main/resources/db/migration/*</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </database>
    <target>
        <clean>true</clean>
        <packageName>my.other.package</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
    </target>
</generator>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What database product are you using, and what's your code generator configuration?

Comment: @LukasEder I updated the question with what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.13, PostgreSQL's typed arrays are not yet supported by the `DDLDatabase`, because the current implementation of the `DDLDatabase` translates your DDL to H2 behind the scenes, and H2 1.4.200's `ARRAY` type does not support any other type of array than `Object[]`.

This will change in the future, as:

1. H2 1.4.201 will support typed arrays like PostgreSQL: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1390
2. jOOQ will support running your DDL on an actual PostgreSQL database in test containers: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551
3. jOOQ will support interpreting the DDL instead of running it on a third party database product: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7034

Until then, in order to use such PostgreSQL-specific features, I recommend using the classic approach of connecting to an actual PostgreSQL database instance.